# How can I merge a signature and my module with an ImageMagick command?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I have this starting situation.
I have a jpg picture (A) with a module in which the signature slot is always in the same place.
I have also a signature (B) jpg picture, separated.

I use a program that allows external calls, but one single line only.

Is there an ImageMagick single command line command that allows me to do

1. Put Image (B) into image (A) at a specific x,y,height and width
2. Consider WHITE #FFFFFF as the alpha channel for image (B)
   ?

I am looking since a while now but haven't figured anything out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick, you would first make white transparent and then overlay B onto A. You need to use parentheses processing to keep the processes separate but in the same command line.

Unix syntax for ImageMagick 6:

```
convert imageA \( imageB -transparent white \) -geometry WxH+X+Y -compose over -composite result
```

or possibly

```
convert imageA \( imageB -transparent white -resize WxH \) -geometry +X+Y -compose over -composite result
```

Best if you provide your input images for demonstration.

See

https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis
https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose
https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/